# time interval between two records

Tags: mysql

hi i got a small problem can u do favor to me on this?

```
SELECT  `name` ,  `mytimestamp` 
FROM  `profile` 
WHERE  `mytimestamp` between '2012-10-24 05:59:00' AND '2012-10-25 05:59:00' 
ORDER BY `name` , `mytimestamp`
```

the above query gives me list around 3000 records from my table, in my table 100 names are present, for those names several timestamps avail,
now my problem is i have to find a name which has 3 hours gap?

i need to do this from a query itself in mysql......

thx to all!

Comment: Are the between times STATIC?

Comment: hi Nilam Doctor thx for reply those times are dynamic

Comment: How about: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff ?

Comment: fatfreddy its valuable info but i'm unable to solve my prob with ur link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will find you all users that have more than one row in profile table, and interval between these two is bigger than `interval`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1 name
FROM profile p1
INNER JOIN profile p2 on p1.name = p2.name
WHERE p2.mytimestamp - p1.mytimestamp > interval;
```

Comment: hi samuil in your query for 3 hours can i use 3 directly instead of interval?

Comment: No, unless you will use some mysql function for this substraction (e.g. `TIMESTAMPDIFF`)

Answer (score -2):

This may help

```
 SELECT *
      FROM table
     WHERE datetime BETWEEN TO_DATE ('10/30/2012 06:00:00',
                                              'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
                                             )
                                 AND TO_DATE ('10/30/2012 16:12:00',
                                              'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
                                             )
                AND  TO_DATE ('10/30/2012 16:12:00',
                                              'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
                                             )-  TO_DATE ('10/30/2012 06:12:00',
                                              'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
                                             )>2
```

Comment: i have test runned in oracle,it may vary a bit in syntax in mysql

Comment: yup sayannays its working in oracle but in mysql it is not working

Comment: just dont use to_date and use as you used like   " between '2012-10-24 05:59:00' AND '2012-10-25 05:59:00' "

Comment: This query is totally unrelated to problem in my opinion. It should not contain any fixed dates...

Comment: @samuil: My guess(i may be totally wrong) he wants to refine data based on the existing data period he already provided

Comment: i'm looking for existing dates in table but i'm passing two dynamic data and times to get records